# Overheating when using File Roller

Tags: overheating, file-roller

Every time I try to compress a folder of about 1 Gb with File Roller I have to stop after a few seconds because my laptop overheats. I've checked the temperature in Psensor and it goes over 85 ºC (cpu usage is near 100%).

I've installed tlp, but it seems to do nothing.

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit on a Dell Latitude D630 Intel Core2 Duo CPU T7500 @ 2.20GHz × 2.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hardware problem... either your fan isn't working or otherwise has airflow blocked, or your system was not designed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check if your CPU fan is working?  CPU temperature should not be that high even if the CPU is under heavy load.

lm-sensors is required for Psensor to read the fan speed.  Another easy way is to hear if there is a difference in the noise when the CPU is idle and when File Roller is running.  If you cannot tell a difference, that will be the problem of CPU fan.

Comment: I can hear clearly the fan increasing its speed as the temperature rises.

Comment: As psusi suggested, in that case there is a chance that the airflow is blocked... If your laptop is already placed in a well ventilated area, you may need to remove the dust over the heat sink or to return the laptop for service.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I've made a simple script in java to stress the cpu and tryed it both in windows and linux and I've found that the cpu gets quickly warm in both of them. So, I think that you're right: the airflow is blocked. I'll try to take apart the laptop and see what's wrong.